# Reading invalid data from dynamic array, maybe its logical problem but i don`t see it

Tags: c++, arrays

pls help, thx for your time 
Task is: create dynamic array, enter data in it and use data for calculation. 
The error is in the condition declaration line of the second "for" loop.
Error code:"С6385", error text:"reading invalid data"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double s, u, h;
int i = 0;
s = 0;

int main(){
    int ar_size;
    cout << "Enter array size" << endl;
    cin >> ar_size;
    int* a = new int[ar_size];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter array data" << endl;
        cin >> a[i];
        cout << "Value of " << i << " element is " << a[i] << endl; //check data
            for (i = 0; a[i] > 0 && a[i] < 3.14; i++) { //problem here, error code:"С6385", error text:"reading invalid data"
             u = 2 * cos(a[i]);
                h = 1 - 2 * sin(a[i]);
                s = s + u / h;
                cout << "When i = " << i << "\t" << "s = " << s << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I`m new at C++, sorry if it stupid question and thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to doubles because that seems more like you application but you had to many i's going on and needed a if block not a for loop. hope this helps

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double u, h, s = {};

int main()
{
    int ar_size;
    cout << "Enter array size" << endl;
    cin >> ar_size;
    double* a = new double[ar_size];
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter array data" << endl;
        string input;
        getline(cin, input);
        a[i] = stod(input);
        cout << "Value of " << i << " element is " << a[i] << endl;
            if(a[i] > 0 && a[i] < 3.14)
            {
                u = 2 * cos(a[i]);
                h = 1 - 2 * sin(a[i]);
                s = s + u / h;
                cout << "When i = " << a[i] << "\t" << "s = " << s << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "out of bounds\n";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I later came to almost the same code, I thought to write my solution here, but it's already here, thanks a lot